# for complex json object @pipe not working in angular4

Tags: angular

I was trying to create pipe feature for table, gone through web got some [example](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/16/angular2-creating-custom-search-filter-pipe-for-ngfor-directive/#comment-1846), I tried to replicate the same but no luck .please help me with this where I went wrong.Thanks!

Find my stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ekoxd3).

Comment: Why are you adding the extra 'Name' when calling your pipe when you are not using it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use this in your searchFilter

return items.filter(it => it[field].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))

Comment: import { Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
 name: 'searchfilter'
})

@Injectable()
export class SearchFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {
   if (!items) return [];
   //return items.filter(it => it[field] == value);
return items.filter(it => it[field].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))
   
   
 }

Comment: <input  [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="first name" />
<table>
 
<tr *ngFor="let item of employees | searchfilter: searchText ">
  <td>
      {{item.Name}}
  </td>
  <td>
      {{item.Last_Name}}
  </td>
</tr>
</table>